# Same File Different Creation Time

Tags: c#, windows, ienumerable, fileinfo

I'm looking at the exact same file, which is returning different creation time between:

- The `FileInfo` instance I pass as the parameter to the function
- The `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` in the function.

Please see below, I'm looking at the same file (name is the same, see red box), but the creation time is different (see green box). How is this possible, and how do I solve it? They should be the same. In fact, this file (`OptionTraderLog-2020-08-31_16_60_02_000018.tce`) should not even appear in the Linq expression (`B`), since I'm looking for all files with a creation time greater than this file.

[image]

See the relevant part of this function:

```
    protected override FileInfo GetNextFile(FileInfo currentLiveFile)
    {
        // currentLiveFile is A)
        // IEnumerable generated below is B)
        var allFilesInDirectory = currentLiveFile.Directory.GetFiles()
                                                           .Where(f => f.CreationTime > currentLiveFile.CreationTime)
                                                           .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f.Name) == _fileExtension)
                                                           .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
        // Rest of function...
    }
```

The windows specified creation time aligns with 10:34:35 AM, but it has both the creation and write time as the same time. I think Windows is considering the `CreationTime` to be the `WriteTime`:

[image]

Comment: Windows allows arbitrary modification of a file's creation, modify, last-write, and last-access times. Depending on the underlying filesystem or network redirector, the timestamps in the in-memory file control block (FCB) or on-disk file record (e.g. the MFT record in NTFS) can be out of sync with the directory entry. Particularly if a file has hard links, the directory entry for a given hardlink will reflect timestamps from the last time it was accessed using that link, which could differ significantly from the current values in the FCB or file record. The directory entry is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling `.Refresh()` on both the `FileInfo` object passed into the function as a parameter, and on each `FileInfo` object in the enumeration (in the `.Where()`) as such:

```
            Func<FileInfo, bool> GreaterCreationTimeThanFile = (f) 
            =>
            {
                f.Refresh();
                return f.CreationTime > currentLiveFile.CreationTime;
            };

//
// currentLiveFile.Directory.GetFiles().Where(GreaterCreationTimeThanFile)....
//
```

Comment: That's still a race condition, you cannot make certain no one will change the timestamps after the `Refresh()` returns.

Comment: @TanveerBadar It's in a folder that I know for a fact that no one will touch.